# Print variable does not work

Tags: assembly, printing, x86-16

Hello this code should take a name and a number and print the name as the number of times I gave it.
However when I look on the memory every thing looks right and I see the name,
but when im coming to do int21 with ah = 09h it doesn't print the name at all
(it should print the name in the `print` label.)

```
org 100h
FirstTime db ' Please type any number: $'
Error db 13,10,'Please type any VALID NUMBER: $'
MyName db 16 dup('$')

mov dx, offset MyName
mov ah, 0Ah
int 21h

mov dx, offset FirstTime
enter:
;Start message/error
mov ah, 09h
int 21h

;Get input - 
mov ah,01h
int 21h
mov bl,al 

;Validation check -
cmp bl, 30h
jae above

;false - return + error msg
mov dx, offset Error
jmp enter


;true
above:
cmp bl,39h
jbe printname
;false - return + error msg
mov dx, offset Error
jmp enter  


;print name(true) - 
printname: 

;dose it 0?
cmp bl, 30h
je finito

;Print name! woho its (not) working!
print:
mov dx, offset MyName
mov ah, 09h
int 21h

dec bl
cmp bl, 30h
jne print

finito:                    
hlt
```

Comment: You're not passing [the right kind of buffer](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah0a) to `int 21h / ah=0ah`. So what's happening is probably that the first `'$'` at `MyName` is still there when you try to print the string, and of course `'$'` is the string terminator for `int 21h / ah=09h`.

Comment: I'm very new with assembler and I just use the '$' sigh because the teacher tolled me so I don't know even what it does can you explain &#128517; like what do I need to do for it to work..

Comment: You need to pass a proper buffer to `int 21h / ah=0ah`, as described on the page I linked to in my previous comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problems starts with a wrong definition of the inputbuffer. The first byte must be the number of bytes you want to allow on input. The second byte will be the number of bytes/characters that were effectively inputed.

```
MyName db 14,0,16 dup('$') ;At least 1 "$" will remain.

mov dx, offset MyName
mov ah, 0Ah
int 21h
```

This also means that you have to change PRINT accordingly.

```
print:
mov dx, 2 + offset MyName
mov ah, 09h
int 21h
```

ps. Does this program run at all? Shouldn't you jump over those data lines!

Answer (score 2):

```
mov dx, offset MyName
add dx, 2
mov ah, 09h
int 21h
```

try it

Comment: Your answer doesn't cope with the true problem in this program. The ouput will appear to be correct but the program will remain to be faulty!